# Confused about the answer to the inverse of a cosine function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\arccos { (\cos { (\frac { 17\pi  }{ 6 } ) }  } )$$

No matter how I try and look at this problem, I end up with $\frac { 5\pi  }{ 6 } $

I counted $\frac { \pi  }{ 6 } $ 17 times counter clockwise around the unit circle and end up at $-\frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 } $ Once I insert it into the parameters of arccosine, This evaluates to $\frac { 5\pi  }{ 6 } $

I double checked my answer on the calculator and it gives me my answer. However, the answer is $\pi/6$

Why is this???

Comment: You are correct, the answer is $\frac{5\pi}6$

Comment: Possibly outer parens are `abs()` signs, not ordinary parentheses? $$\arccos\left|\cos\left(\frac{17\pi}6\right)\right|$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=\arccos\left[\cos\frac{17\pi}6\right]$

Using the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) of  Principal values $0\le y\le\pi$

Now $\cos y=\cos\dfrac{17\pi}6\implies y=2m\pi\pm\dfrac{17\pi}6=\dfrac{\pi(12m\pm17)}6$ where $m$ is any integer

So, we need $0\le\dfrac{\pi(12m\pm17)}6\le\pi\iff0\le12m\pm17\le6$

Taking the '+' sign, $0\le12m+17\le6\iff-17\le12m\le-11\implies m=-1 $

$\implies y=\dfrac{\pi[12(-1)+17]}6$

Taking the '-' sign, $0\le12m-17\le6\iff17\le12m\le23\implies $ no integer $m$